# My code with truncate() appends new data instead of replacing old data

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code below is supposed to delete the content of the file and write the new strings that user enters through terminal, but in reality it only appends new line to what is already there. I can't seem to make it fully erase the content with `truncate()`. How do I do this?

**Note**: it has to be done with `truncate()` as it's an exercise from the book and I don't want to jump into the future and use any more advanced stuff.
Thanks!

```
from sys import argv
script, filename, user_name = argv
print("Hi my dear %s... I hope you're doing great today\n" % user_name)
print("We're going to write a string to a file %r\n" % filename)
open_file = open(filename, 'r+')
print("%s, this is what currently file %r has" % (user_name, filename))
read_file = open_file.read()
print("File's content is:\n", read_file)
quote = "To create, first sometime you need to destroy"
print("\n\nAs a quote from your favourite movie says: \n\n %r" \
    % quote)
print("So, we will delete the content from the file %r" \
    % filename)
open_file.truncate()
print("This is the file %r now" % filename)
print(read_file)

new_line = input("Now let's write something, please start here... ")

print("now %s, let's add this line to the same file %r" \
    % (user_name, filename))
open_file.write(new_line)
print("Closing the file")
open_file.close()
print(read_file)
open_file.close()
```

Comment: Several others have mentioned the better way to do it, which is probably shorthand for `open_file.seek(0); open_file.truncate()`, which is what I've always done.

Answer (score 2):

[`truncate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.truncate) without any arguments truncates at the current position. Pass a size to make it truncate the file to that size.

Answer (score 1):

The [`truncate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.truncate) method has an optional `size` argument which defaults to the current position of the file pointer. Since you've already called `read` on the file, `truncate` isn't doing anything as the current position is the end of the file.

Change your call to `truncate(0)` and it'll clear the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot tzaman, I added (0) and it worked as expected. I wasn't aware about the pointer and the needed file size